# tvOS - In app purchase throws "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" error

Tags: objective-c, in-app-purchase, tvos

I am trying to implement the In App Purchase in tvOS.
I configure everything in Xcode and iTunesConnect but when I try to test the In App it throws this error:

> Cannot connect to iTunes Store.

I don't get any alert on my Apple TV to confirm the purchase.

This is the code:

```
- (IBAction)tapsRemoveAds{
    NSLog(@"User requests to remove ads");

    if([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments]){
        NSLog(@"User can make payments");

        //If you have more than one in-app purchase, and would like
        //to have the user purchase a different product, simply define
        //another function and replace kRemoveAdsProductIdentifier with
        //the identifier for the other product

        self.request= [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObject:kRemoveAdsProductIdentifier]];
        self.request.delegate = self;
        [self.request start];
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"User cannot make payments due to parental controls");
        //this is called the user cannot make payments, most likely due to parental controls
    }
}

- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response{
    SKProduct *validProduct = nil;
    NSInteger count = [response.products count];
    if(count > 0){
        validProduct = [response.products objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"Products Available!");
        [self purchase:validProduct];
    }
    else if(!validProduct){
        NSLog(@"No products available");
        //this is called if your product id is not valid, this shouldn't be called unless that happens.
    }
}

- (IBAction)purchase:(SKProduct *)product{
    SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product];

    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
}

- (IBAction) restore{
    //this is called when the user restores purchases, you should hook this up to a button
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}

- (void) paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
{
    NSLog(@"received restored transactions: %lu", (unsigned long)queue.transactions.count);
    for(SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in queue.transactions){
        if(transaction.transactionState == SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored){
            //called when the user successfully restores a purchase
            NSLog(@"Transaction state -> Restored");

            [self doRemoveAds];
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
            break;
        }
    }
}

- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions{
    for(SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions){
        switch(transaction.transactionState){
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing: NSLog(@"Transaction state -> Purchasing");
                //called when the user is in the process of purchasing, do not add any of your own code here.
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                //this is called when the user has successfully purchased the package (Cha-Ching!)
                [self doRemoveAds]; //you can add your code for what you want to happen when the user buys the purchase here, for this tutorial we use removing ads
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                NSLog(@"Transaction state -> Purchased");
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                NSLog(@"Transaction state -> Restored");
                //add the same code as you did from SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased here
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                //called when the transaction does not finish
                if(transaction.error.code == SKErrorPaymentCancelled){
                    NSLog(@"Transaction state -> Cancelled");
                    //the user cancelled the payment ;(
                }
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateDeferred:
                NSLog(@"deffered");
                break;
}
    }
}
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manage to solve the issue with Signing out from iTunes account in Settings->Accounts-> iTunes and Appstore and then the app asked me for credentials and I entered the test credentials. Everything works fine.

PS. Do not use NSUserDefault for saving the purchase result as I did on the sample code. This was a testing code and NSUserDefault won't work as expected(iOS)